# Split spring boot app into multiple web apps

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to split a large web app into different sections.
In my case there is a webshop, an api service, and then the main app.

and all of them should share a domain layer.

I'm trying to reproduce an ear layout without using a enterprise server, so the main app would be a war with a shared domain jar, and the admin app would have a contextPath /admin and also share the same domain.jar.

From start they would be deployed together but as the app grows I would simply start deploying the apps on there own ports and use nginx to glue them together.

I've implemented most of it in this demo github repo.

https://github.com/leon/springboot-multiproject

**My question is:**
How can I map the admin app to a sub directory of the main app?

/admin <- Admin app

/ <- Main app

and do I need to take any special considerations when it comes to the domain layer?

See https://github.com/leon/springboot-multiproject/blob/master/src/main/java/se/radley/main/Application.java#L23

Comment: If I understand correctly, the admin app and the main app will not be part of the same jar (or war if you don't use embedded tomcat). Is that correct? Are you going to be deploying the separately?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce an ear layout without using a enterprise server, so the main app would be a war with a shared domain jar, and the admin app would have a contextPath or /admin and also share the same domain.jar. From start they would be deployed together but as the app grows I would simply start deploying the apps on there own ports and use nginx to glue them together. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You should probably update the question with that info

Comment: I think you need to say what you tried explicitly and how it failed. Deploying 2 war files to a container is a pretty normal thing to do, so you might need to provide more detailed steps to reproduce.

Comment: I don't want to create an ear file, i want to create a spring boot single jar file that can run by itself. but that contains in essens two web apps with a shared domain

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a particularly easy way to completely separate the parts of your application. One option might be to create two ApplicationContexts and spin-up two Tomcat servers, but then they will obviously need to run on different ports.

I would be tempted to keep things simple initially. You could create separate jars for your 'main' and 'admin' `@Controllers`, one for your domain and keep the application jar containing configuration. Component scanning will work withing nested jars so a single `DispatcherServlet` can happily server both the `/admin` and `/` controllers.

Either that, or perhaps just bite the bullet and break-up your applications from the start. At least that way you will be aware of any architectural issues early.

Comment: In play framework you can split the routes by using the /admin <- admin.Routes. Is there something similar in spring so I don't have to prefix all my admin controllers with /admin ?

Comment: You can add `@RequestMapping` at the Class level and the method level.

Comment: Say I already have compiled a jar with some functionality (a couple of controllers) and I want to import them into another project then I would need to recompile the jar and change the RequestMapping for those controllers. It doesn't seem optimal

Comment: You can also use "${}" placeholders in the annotations. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value-- javadoc and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9935 for background

Comment: Thanks Phil that helps alot :)